# select2 - submit form with android search button

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, jquery-select2

My site uses a select2 3.5.3 multiple select field with a search box. On mobile devices, the keyboard that pops ups when the search box is focused includes a search button. Currently, the search button does nothing (I assume it's behaving like the 'enter' key, which select2 uses to confirm a selection, but not submit).

I would like the mobile keyboard's search button to submit the users query if, and only if they have already made a selection. Is there a way to do this?

Here's the relevant select2 code:

```js
function formatPerson(person) {
  // select2: template for people results display
  if (person.loading) return person.text;

  if (person.known_for[0]) {
    var known = person.known_for[0].title
  } else {
    var known = ""
  }

  var markup = '<div><object type="image/jpg" data="https://image.tmdb.org/t/p/w45' +
    person.profile_path +
    '"><img id="placeholder" src="/static/images/logo_placeholder.png"></object> <strong>' +
    person.name +
    "</strong> ( <em>" +
    known +
    "</em> )</div>";

  return markup;
}

function formatPersonSelection(person) {
  // select2: how the people results appear once selected
  return person.name;
}

$('.people_query').select2({
  // select2: ajax code for people search
  ajax: {
    url: "https://api.themoviedb.org/3/search/person?api_key=3b6e9eed30447d42a82fa925134de4ff&language=en-US",
    dataType: 'json',
    delay: 250,
    data: function(params) {
      return {
        query: params.term, // search term
      };
    },
    processResults: function(data, params) {
      return {
        // "data" is the object returned, "results" is the name of the array in the object
        results: data.results,
      };
    },
    cache: true
  }, // ajax
  escapeMarkup: function(markup) {
    return markup;
  }, // custom formatter from Select2
  minimumInputLength: 3,
  language: {
    inputTooShort: function() {
      return 'Search for a person...';
    }
  },
  maximumSelectionLength: 2,
  templateResult: formatPerson,
  templateSelection: formatPersonSelection,

}); //select2 params
```

Comment: You should post some code to go with your question.

Comment: Fair enough. The problem seems to be generic (I get it with the default examples from select2's page), but I've updated to include the code I'm actually running.